# Cocoa - Reorder NSTableView columns programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` with 4 columns. I would like to control the order of each column from code.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question: I used 'moveColumn' to achieve it.